# Ubuntu on Pi 4 -- How to enable lan over usb-c?

Tags: ubuntu, usb-c

I want to activate lan over USB-C on my Raspberry Pi running Ubuntu 20.10
Is it possible?

I have seen guides for raspbian but (https://www.hardill.me.uk/wordpress/2019/11/02/pi4-usb-c-gadget/) but couldn't find any for ubuntu

Comment: If you don't get an anwer, I suggest you try out a guide for Raspbian: both OS are derived from Debian and are not drastically different.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I'm not sure. Doesn't Ubuntu use **netplan** for networking? Haven't seen it before.